# how to get data from a dynamic dataColumn in datatable mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a dataTable in which some columns are added dynamically. Now i want to get a dynamic dataColumn data from the dataTable.

```
List<bool> EngColumnData = new List<bool>(ResultsGrid.Rows.Count);
        foreach(DataRow row in ResultsGrid.Rows)
        {
            EngColumnData.Add((bool)row["EnglishAchieved"]);
        }
```

The above code works if the column is actually present in the dataTable. I am not sure about the dynamic Column.

Please help me with this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you can get list of columns names have in dynamic data DataTabel , like below ,

```
foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) {
    List.Add(col.ColumnName);
}
```

this will give you list of columns

Then after get data coresponding to that data coloumns like below ,

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) {
    Console.WriteLine(row[List.First()]);
}
```

You can use this way to solve your problem.